# SharePoint 2010 hosted applications migrating to O365

Tags: 2010, office-365

Probably a stupid question that i believe i know the answer to already. I have a sharepoint 2010 farm with some wsp applications. I need them to work in Office 365 so i am assuming they would need to be rewritten as provider hosted apps and then host them somewhere like azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be the path you need to follow

Answer (score 1):

The given answer is correct, but be aware that there is now an additional option besides provider hosted apps. Those sorts of apps (add-ins), are now being superseded by the "SharePoint Framework" for web parts, as well as other Azure technologies for other types of solutions. See [this document](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) for an overview.